# How to get environment variable from Quasar Framework

Tags: vuejs2, quasar

The environment variables are defined in `config/` directory `prod.env.js` and `dev.env.js`, how to get those variable on `.vue` file?

I've tried using `process.env.MY_VAR` assuming it's nodejs built-in library, it gives an error:

```
[=======             ] 34% (building modules){ SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:5)
```

The minimal code in `.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <q-layout>
    <div class="layout-view">
          <button class="primary" @click="foo">
            <i class="on-left">lock</i> Login
          </button>
    </div>
  </q-layout>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return { url: '' }
    }
    methods: {
      foo: function() {
        this.url = process.env.MY_VAR // no error if commented
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

What's the correct way to get those environment variable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `dev.env.js` and `prod.env.js` you write something like:

```
module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  MY_VAR: '"something"'
})
```

Then you can use `process.env.MY_VAR` in your Quasar app code.

Notice the quote + double quote. The build process in Quasar uses Webpack's DefinePlugin (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) which requires a JSON encoded value. Use `JSON.stringify()` for more complex values like JS Objects.

Comment: Quasar is awesome!

Comment: what version is this for?